# Best cut of meat to pair with Gorgonzola?

Tags: cheese, beef, pairing, venison

I've often enjoyed lightly seasoned beef or venison steaks paired with Gorgonzola cheese. Is there any cut of meat that goes particularly well with that particular cheese, or does it not particularly matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this depends on the type of Gorgonzola.  A Gorgonzola Dolcé has a milder, sweeter, less-blue flavor, so it should probably be served with a milder steak, like a Filet Mignon.  A stronger, more traditional Gorgonzola should probably be served with a stronger flavored steak like a Skirt Steak or a Ribeye.  If you flip the combinations around, one of the flavors is going to be lost.

I'm not familiar enough with Venison or other game to comment on their compatibility with Gorgonzola.